# Prove $T$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, alternative-proof

If $T\in L(X,X)$ where $X$ is a Banach space and $L(X,X)$ is denoted as the space of bounded linear maps, and $\|I-T\|<1$ where $I$ is the identity operator, then $T$ is invertible?

Here invertible means $T$ is bijective and $T^{-1}$ is bounded. I can prove $T$ is injective but fail to show $T$ is surjective. In fact, we can find $T^{-1}=\sum_0^\infty(I-T)^n$, which can help prove the surjection. But without knowing this, how to prove? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you show surjectivity? That for each $y\in X$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $Tx=y$. So let $y\in X$ and set $x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (I - T)^n y$. Does this still feel like you're not showing surjectivity directly?

Comment: @Roland I think the point is that this method uses the geometric series expression of the inverse, which I think OP sees as "overkill". That is, might it be possible to prove the existence of an inverse without coming up with some explicit expression for it?

Comment: @Roland Yes, exactly. That's my concern!

Answer (score 1):

> Lemma: If $\Vert X \Vert <1 $, $I-X$ is invertible.

*Proof:* $X^{n+1}-I=(X-I)(I+X+X^2+...+X^n)$. Passing the limit, where we know the right side converges due to the fact that $X$ is a Banach space, together with the fact that the series is absolutely convergent (due to comparison with geometric series), and we know the left side converges to $-I$ since $\Vert X^n \Vert \rightarrow 0$, we have that 
$$-I=(X-I) \sum X^n$$
$$\implies I=(I-X) \sum X^n.$$

The above proof can also be easily adapted to show that $ I=(\sum X^n) (I-X) $, and we have the result. $\blacksquare$

Now to your proposition. Since $\Vert I-T \Vert <1$, we have that $I-(I-T)=T$ is invertible. The result now follows completely from the open mapping theorem.

---

OBS: I did not know what you meant by "without knowing this", and neither exactly what "this" was. If my answer does not address your question, please clarify.

Comment: More generally: If $\sum_{i=1}^n S^i$ is convergent in $L(X,X)$, then $I-S$ invertible.

Comment: Thanks, Aloizio. "Without knowing this" means that I am not clever to be able to find the expression of $T^{-1}$. Just based on the fact that $T$ is linear, bounded and injective, can you show that $T$ is surjective? I am now thinking for a open ball $B(0,\delta)\in X$, is $T(B(0,\delta))$ open or whether $0$ is in $T(B(0,\delta))$?

Comment: and for the boundedness of $(I-T)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Well, I am not clever enough to solve this without using what I did :P. Jokes aside, I don't see how to "elementarize" this. For instance, I use the fact that an absolutely convergent series must itself converge, and this is special of Banach spaces. Also, I use the open mapping theorem, which require some sort of completeness as well. It seems to me you would have to infuse those facts in your "elementary" proof, and would turn out to be quite cumbersome. But I may be very wrong.

Comment: Is the opposite of the claim also true? If we know $I-X$ is invertible, can we claim $\|X\|<1$?

Comment: @user760 No, already in $\mathbb{R}$ we have that, for example, $X=10$ is such that $I-X=-9$ is invertible, but $\lVert X \rVert = 10 > 1$.